# Too long button's content in WP7 CustomMessageBox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, toolkit

In my application I need to create MessageBox with custom options. So I have found CustomMessageBox from WPtoolkit and I have used it. But I have some **problem** with too long content in buttons:

[image]

Is there a way to wrap text inside buttons there?

Answer (score 0):

You can not, these are the standard sizes, and you cannot make them grow according to your needs, the same happens with XNA Gamerservice messagebox. Best practice is to use UI Popups.